# Odoo domain filter as attributes

Tags: filter, attributes, odoo, eval

Hello I like to apply an eval expression for my domain, so I can include an XML id to check with.

I tried this, but no results, any idea how I can achieve this?

```
<field name="product_id" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="domain" eval="[('id', '=', ref('productgroep_kaders')]/>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
1) If you are giving domain inside any field definition then you need to define domain as like below.

```
<field name="product_id" position="attributes"
    domain="[('id', '=', %('productgroep_kaders')d)]" />
```

Or:
2) If you inherit any view and add just domain attribute then you need to define domain as like below.

```
<field name="product_id" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="domain">"[('id', '=', %('productgroep_kaders')d)]"</attribute>
</field>
```